# Ruby sound playback

Tags: ruby, audio

This is 2009, back in 2001 or so, there used to be no good bindings for sound playback in ruby.

Has there been a change?  I am looking for something to control playback of either raw sound or mp3, ogg and flac.  My Googling has turned up dry.

Edit:  Linux, OSX and if possible Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't mention a platform. [This page](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2007/05/adding-sound-to-your-ruby-apps.html) describes the win32-sound library, which seems to support at least WAV playback.

For a more platform-neutral way, [Ruby/SDL](http://www.kmc.gr.jp/~ohai/rubysdl.en.html) provides bindings for the ever-popular [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) library.

Comment: That's true I didn't.  I had found the win32-sound library but it's rather horrid.  Also, windows support is not very pressing.  I'm more interested in Linux and OSX, but I don't want to be too hasty in removing Windows.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I took a quick look at how SDL does playback and it probably will work out.  I had initially overlooked it because it is such a large library.  Thank you unwind.

Comment: rubygame is another useful SDL binding :)

Comment: `rubygame` speeds up my audio so that all my speech sounds like chipmunks